# Angular4 - My script events doesn't work after routerLink click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I'm new in angular. I have a script in jquery sintax and this scripts are many efects over my dom. When I start application the script works perfectly but after click in any routerLink inside a dom the mouse events dosen't work, just click events. Any ideia about this problem? Tks!

Example of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.material.init();


    $("#side-menu").children().children().mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('_active');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('_active');
    });
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using Angular code/components/directives instead of using JQuery.

Comment: Why not use CSS hover for adding/removing styles on hover? If that's not an option, why not [Angular Event Binding Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-)? Is `#side-menu` inside the page content or is outside `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I'm not sure how to use Angular Events yet. And I have many other scripts in jquery that dosen't work. '#side-menu' is inside.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery with Angular? If you want to use jQuery, just stick with jQuery, no need to add the overhead of an entire Angular application if you're not going to use it. I advise you remove jQuery from your project and just use Angular directly. It arguably easier to achieve what you want with Angular alone because you just need to use events like `(click)="handleClick($event)"` and so on on your elements. It's as simple as that.,

Comment: create a directive for this